# How can I find the shortest path for all nodes in a graph from a source $s$?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

This is the shortest path problem. I've used a model where we can find the shortest path between the source and a specified destination.

The idea behind this model is that we assign a flow of 1 for the source and -1 for the destination and every other node has a flow of 0 because they're acting as transfer only.

However, I want to find the shortest path for every node in the graph from the source. It's similar to what the Dijkstra algorithm does however I want to use linear programming.

How can I adapt the model to give me the shortest path for every node in the graph from the source?
Here's how the original model I used looks like.

[![graph][1]][1]

Where x12 is the arc from edge 1 to edge 2.

The basic idea would be to have all edges with a flow of -1 however when I try this it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.
the graph used :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8yuT.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm finds a shortest path from $s$ to all other nodes in $N \setminus\{s\}$.  The corresponding linear programming problem is to minimize $$\sum_{(i,j)\in A} c_{i,j} x_{i,j}$$ subject to
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in A} x_{i,j} - \sum_{(j,i)\in A} x_{j,i} = 
\begin{cases}
n-1 &\text{for $i=s$}\\
-1 &\text{for $i\in N \setminus \{s\}$}
\end{cases}$$
and $x_{i,j}\ge 0$ for all $(i,j)\in A$.

That is, node $s$ has a supply of $n-1$, and every other node has a demand of $1$.

Comment: I think the question needs to find the shortest path (route) to visit all nodes and visit all nodes at least once. The formulation you provided calculates a different issue. it creates a connected graph covering all nodes (like MST)

Comment: @Optimizationteam I think my interpretation of the question is correct, and the OP accepted my answer.  For your related question, I added an answer just now: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10762/how-to-find-the-shortest-path-visiting-all-nodes-in-a-connected-graph-as-milp