TSP with Optional Nodes
Suppose I have a graph  $G(N,V)$, where $V = R\cup S$. $R$ is a set of nodes which must be visited, $S$ is a set of supporting nodes, i.e. nodes which can be used to build the route.
The graph is described by an adjacency matrix $\mathrm{A}$. I already computed the distance matrix $\mathrm{D}$, i.e. the pairs of all shortest path between two nodes.
So, I am asked to build the optimal route which visits at least all the nodes in $R$.
How can I cast the problem into TSP? Shall I use the $\mathrm{D}$ or the adjacency matrix $\mathrm{A}$?
BFS or DFS could be useful?
I tried with this formulation (taken from a paper)

with this code:
# Create a Concrete Model
n = len(R)
starting_node = 'S_44'
model = ConcreteModel()
model.constraints = ConstraintList()

model.E = Set(initialize=edges.keys())
model.R = Set(initialize=R)  # Define set R
model.S = Set(initialize=S)     # Define set S
model.V = Set(initialize=R+S)

model.d = Param(model.V, model.V, initialize=dist_matrix)

# Variables
model.x = Var(model.E, within=NonNegativeIntegers)  # Decision variables x_ij
model.y = Var(model.E, within=NonNegativeReals)  # Additional variables y_ij
 

# Objective function
def objective_rule(model):    
    return sum(model.d[i,j] * model.x[i,j] for i,j in model.E   )

model.obj = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize)
#SCSF forumaltion
model.cons0 = ConstraintList()
for e,neigh in test_adj.items():   
     if e in model.R:
        model.cons0.add( sum(model.x[e, j] for j in neigh if j!= e) == 1) 
        
# Constraint 1  
model.cons1 = ConstraintList()

for e,neigh in test_adj.items(): 
    if e in model.V:
        model.cons1.add(sum(model.x[e, j] for j in neigh if j!= e ) ==
                        sum(model.x[j, e] for j in neigh if j!= e ))

# Constraint 2,3 Flow Conservation
model.cons2 = ConstraintList() 
model.cons3 = ConstraintList() 
for i,neigh in test_adj.items(): 
    if i in model.R and i != starting_node:
        model.cons2.add(sum(model.y[e, i] - model.y[i,e] for e in neigh) == 1 ) 
 
for i,neigh in test_adj.items(): 
    if i in model.S and i != starting_node:
        model.cons3.add(sum(model.y[e, i] - model.y[i,e] for e in neigh) == 0 ) 
 
#Commodity
model.cons4 = ConstraintList()
for i, j in model.E:
    model.cons4.add(model.y[i, j] >= len(R) *  model.x[i,j])

but the solutions found are not good
Edges with x=1:
x[S_02,v_12] = 1.0
x[S_04,v_14] = 1.0
x[v_12,S_02] = 1.0
x[v_13,v_23] = 1.0
x[v_23,v_13] = 1.0
x[v_33,v_43] = 1.0
x[v_43,v_33] = 1.0
x[v_14,S_04] = 1.0
x[v_24,v_34] = 1.0
x[v_34,v_24] = 1.0
x[v_44,v_54] = 1.0
x[v_54,v_44] = 1.0

I drawn the graph with networks:

The adjacency matrix is:
{'S_22': {'S_02': 60, 'S_33': 60, 'v_12': 51.75},
 'S_02': {'S_22': 60, 'S_03': 30, 'v_12': 8.25},
 'S_33': {'S_03': 90,
  'S_22': 60,
  'S_44': 60,
  'v_13': 81.75,
  'v_23': 73.5,
  'v_33': 65.25,
  'v_43': 57},
 'S_03': {'S_33': 90, 'S_02': 30, 'S_04': 30, 'v_13': 8.25},
 'S_44': {'S_04': 120,
  'S_33': 60,
  'v_14': 111.75,
  'v_24': 103.5,
  'v_34': 95.25,
  'v_44': 87,
  'v_54': 78.75},
 'S_04': {'S_44': 120, 'S_03': 30, 'v_14': 8.25},
 'v_12': {'S_02': 8.25, 'S_22': 51.75},
 'v_13': {'S_03': 8.25, 'S_33': 81.75, 'v_23': 8.25},
 'v_23': {'v_13': 8.25, 'S_33': 73.5, 'v_33': 8.250000000000004},
 'v_33': {'v_23': 8.250000000000004, 'S_33': 65.25, 'v_43': 8.249999999999996},
 'v_43': {'v_33': 8.249999999999996, 'S_33': 57},
 'v_14': {'S_04': 8.25, 'S_44': 111.75, 'v_24': 8.25},
 'v_24': {'v_14': 8.25, 'S_44': 103.5, 'v_34': 8.250000000000004},
 'v_34': {'v_24': 8.250000000000004, 'S_44': 95.25, 'v_44': 8.249999999999996},
 'v_44': {'v_34': 8.249999999999996, 'S_44': 87, 'v_54': 8.25},
 'v_54': {'v_44': 8.25, 'S_44': 78.75}}

and the distance matrix is:
{"S_22":{"S_22":0,"S_02":60,"S_33":60,"S_03":90,"S_44":120,"S_04":120,"v_12":51.75,"v_13":98.25,"v_23":106.5,"v_33":114.75,"v_43":117,"v_14":128.25,"v_24":136.5,"v_34":144.75,"v_44":153,"v_54":161.25},"S_02":{"S_22":60,"S_02":0,"S_33":120,"S_03":30,"S_44":180,"S_04":60,"v_12":8.25,"v_13":38.25,"v_23":46.5,"v_33":54.75,"v_43":63,"v_14":68.25,"v_24":76.5,"v_34":84.75,"v_44":93,"v_54":101.25},"S_33":{"S_22":60,"S_02":120,"S_33":0,"S_03":90,"S_44":60,"S_04":120,"v_12":111.75,"v_13":81.75,"v_23":73.5,"v_33":65.25,"v_43":57,"v_14":128.25,"v_24":136.5,"v_34":144.75,"v_44":147,"v_54":138.75},"S_03":{"S_22":90,"S_02":30,"S_33":90,"S_03":0,"S_44":150,"S_04":30,"v_12":38.25,"v_13":8.25,"v_23":16.5,"v_33":24.750000000000004,"v_43":33,"v_14":38.25,"v_24":46.5,"v_34":54.75,"v_44":63,"v_54":71.25},"S_44":{"S_22":120,"S_02":180,"S_33":60,"S_03":150,"S_44":0,"S_04":120,"v_12":171.75,"v_13":141.75,"v_23":133.5,"v_33":125.25,"v_43":117,"v_14":111.75,"v_24":103.5,"v_34":95.25,"v_44":87,"v_54":78.75},"S_04":{"S_22":120,"S_02":60,"S_33":120,"S_03":30,"S_44":120,"S_04":0,"v_12":68.25,"v_13":38.25,"v_23":46.5,"v_33":54.75,"v_43":63,"v_14":8.25,"v_24":16.5,"v_34":24.750000000000004,"v_44":33,"v_54":41.25},"v_12":{"S_22":51.75,"S_02":8.25,"S_33":111.75,"S_03":38.25,"S_44":171.75,"S_04":68.25,"v_12":0,"v_13":46.5,"v_23":54.75,"v_33":63,"v_43":71.25,"v_14":76.5,"v_24":84.75,"v_34":93,"v_44":101.25,"v_54":109.5},"v_13":{"S_22":98.25,"S_02":38.25,"S_33":81.75,"S_03":8.25,"S_44":141.75,"S_04":38.25,"v_12":46.5,"v_13":0,"v_23":8.25,"v_33":16.500000000000004,"v_43":24.75,"v_14":46.5,"v_24":54.75,"v_34":63,"v_44":71.25,"v_54":79.5},"v_23":{"S_22":106.5,"S_02":46.5,"S_33":73.5,"S_03":16.5,"S_44":133.5,"S_04":46.5,"v_12":54.75,"v_13":8.25,"v_23":0,"v_33":8.250000000000004,"v_43":16.5,"v_14":54.75,"v_24":63,"v_34":71.25,"v_44":79.5,"v_54":87.75},"v_33":{"S_22":114.75,"S_02":54.75,"S_33":65.25,"S_03":24.750000000000004,"S_44":125.25,"S_04":54.75,"v_12":63,"v_13":16.500000000000004,"v_23":8.250000000000004,"v_33":0,"v_43":8.249999999999996,"v_14":63,"v_24":71.25,"v_34":79.5,"v_44":87.75,"v_54":96},"v_43":{"S_22":117,"S_02":63,"S_33":57,"S_03":33,"S_44":117,"S_04":63,"v_12":71.25,"v_13":24.75,"v_23":16.5,"v_33":8.249999999999996,"v_43":0,"v_14":71.25,"v_24":79.5,"v_34":87.75,"v_44":96,"v_54":104.25},"v_14":{"S_22":128.25,"S_02":68.25,"S_33":128.25,"S_03":38.25,"S_44":111.75,"S_04":8.25,"v_12":76.5,"v_13":46.5,"v_23":54.75,"v_33":63,"v_43":71.25,"v_14":0,"v_24":8.25,"v_34":16.500000000000004,"v_44":24.75,"v_54":33},"v_24":{"S_22":136.5,"S_02":76.5,"S_33":136.5,"S_03":46.5,"S_44":103.5,"S_04":16.5,"v_12":84.75,"v_13":54.75,"v_23":63,"v_33":71.25,"v_43":79.5,"v_14":8.25,"v_24":0,"v_34":8.250000000000004,"v_44":16.5,"v_54":24.75},"v_34":{"S_22":144.75,"S_02":84.75,"S_33":144.75,"S_03":54.75,"S_44":95.25,"S_04":24.750000000000004,"v_12":93,"v_13":63,"v_23":71.25,"v_33":79.5,"v_43":87.75,"v_14":16.500000000000004,"v_24":8.250000000000004,"v_34":0,"v_44":8.249999999999996,"v_54":16.499999999999996},"v_44":{"S_22":153,"S_02":93,"S_33":147,"S_03":63,"S_44":87,"S_04":33,"v_12":101.25,"v_13":71.25,"v_23":79.5,"v_33":87.75,"v_43":96,"v_14":24.75,"v_24":16.5,"v_34":8.249999999999996,"v_44":0,"v_54":8.25},"v_54":{"S_22":161.25,"S_02":101.25,"S_33":138.75,"S_03":71.25,"S_44":78.75,"S_04":41.25,"v_12":109.5,"v_13":79.5,"v_23":87.75,"v_33":96,"v_43":104.25,"v_14":33,"v_24":24.75,"v_34":16.499999999999996,"v_44":8.25,"v_54":0}}


Does this answer your question? How to visit a subset of network nodes in a single trip?

Hi, thank you. It is very similar but I need a route back to the source. So the algotihm shall output the path, the sequence of nodes, to follow in order to visit the required nodes and go back home...

In the accepted answer to the linked question, just don’t change the distances back to the source to zero.

See also https://or.stackexchange.com/a/10763/500

@RobPratt ok, but to me is quite difficult to implement it...it is not quite clear...

@RobPratt so I don't have to change the distance matrix?

Here's a way to solve the problem with two calls to the network solver in SAS (disclaimer: I work for SAS).
data LinkData;
   input from $ to $ cost;
   datalines;
S_22 S_33 60.00 
S_22 v_12 51.75 
S_02 S_22 60.00 
S_02 S_03 30.00 
S_02 v_12 8.25 
S_33 S_44 60.00 
S_33 v_13 81.75 
S_33 v_23 73.50 
S_33 v_33 65.25 
S_33 v_43 57.00 
S_03 S_33 90.00 
S_03 S_04 30.00 
S_03 v_13 8.25 
S_44 v_14 111.75 
S_44 v_24 103.50 
S_44 v_34 95.25 
S_44 v_44 87.00 
S_44 v_54 78.75 
S_04 S_44 120.00 
S_04 v_14 8.25 
v_13 v_23 8.25 
v_23 v_33 8.25 
v_33 v_43 8.25 
v_14 v_24 8.25 
v_24 v_34 8.25 
v_34 v_44 8.25 
v_44 v_54 8.25 
;

data MustNodeData;
   input node $;
   datalines;
v_12 
v_13 
v_14 
v_23 
v_24 
v_33 
v_34 
v_43 
v_44 
v_54 
;

proc optmodel;
   /* read input data */
   set <str,str> LINKS;
   num cost {LINKS};
   read data LinkData into LINKS=[from to] cost;
   set NODES = union {<i,j> in LINKS} {i,j};
   set <str> MUSTNODES;
   read data MustNodeData into MUSTNODES=[node];
   print cost;

   /* solve all-pairs shortest path problem in original graph */
   set PAIRS = {i in MUSTNODES, j in MUSTNODES: i < j};
   num d {PAIRS} init 0;
   solve with network / shortpath=(source=MUSTNODES sink=MUSTNODES) links=(weight=cost) out=(spweights=d);
   print d;

   /* solve traveling salesman problem in complete graph on MUSTNODES */
   set <str,str> TOUR;
   solve with network / tsp links=(weight=d) out=(tour=TOUR);
   print {<i,j> in TOUR} d;
quit;

The shortest-path distances are:
     v_13  v_14  v_23  v_24  v_33  v_34  v_43  v_44   v_54 
v_12 46.50 76.50 54.75 84.75 63.00 93.00 71.25 101.25 109.50 
v_13       46.50  8.25 54.75 16.50 63.00 24.75  71.25  79.50 
v_14             54.75  8.25 63.00 16.50 71.25  24.75  33.00 
v_23                   63.00  8.25 71.25 16.50  79.50  87.75 
v_24                         71.25  8.25 79.50  16.50  24.75 
v_33                               79.50  8.25  87.75  96.00 
v_34                                     87.75   8.25  16.50 
v_43                                            96.00 104.25 
v_44                                                    8.25 

An optimal TSP tour (with objective value 285) is as follows:
v_12 v_13  46.50 
v_12 v_54 109.50 
v_13 v_23   8.25 
v_14 v_24   8.25 
v_14 v_43  71.25 
v_23 v_33   8.25 
v_24 v_34   8.25 
v_33 v_43   8.25 
v_34 v_44   8.25 
v_44 v_54   8.25 

Now expand each link in the tour to a shortest path in the original graph.
